# Does anybody have the PDP-11 CAPS-11 source code?

Tags: pdp-11

CAPS-11 is the Casette Programming System for the PDP-11. The [manual](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/dec/pdp11/caps-11/DEC-11-OTUGA-A-D_CAPS-11_Users_Guide_Oct73.pdf) is available at Bitsavers, [binaries](http://simh.trailing-edge.com/software.html) can be found at SimH.

The manual contains instructions how to assemble the system from source, the source code should be available somewhere.

I have disassembled the code, but annotated source would be really useful. I have googled around and not found anything.

(I am 100% pdp11 novice writing pdp11 emulator from scratch for kicks)

Comment: It would help if you'd say for **what** you'd like some source code ... there's plenty of PDP-11 stuff around. If you want to understand PDP-11 assembly, there's also plenty of documention around.

Comment: @dirkt caps-11 is an operating system for PDP-11

Comment: I think the answer is going to be no.

Comment: @dirkt i said I would like the source of CAPS11 the binary of this cassette based OS is on simh sw site. THere is a nice manual too.http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/caps-11/DEC-11-OTUGA-A-D_CAPS-11_Users_Guide_Oct73.pdf.

Comment: I concur that the likely answer is 'no' (given bitsavers does not have it) but the question is now clear enough, if "needs clarity" was the reason to close. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @JeremyP happily the answer was 'yes'

Comment: I took the assumed "no" as a bit of a challenge (-;

Comment: @hippietrail Did you get the source? The links on your answer were to RSX-11, but you did mention getting the source for CAPS-11.

Comment: @JeremyP: I didn't get it but the OP did. I think they're trying to find out how to get a copy to bitsavers to put up. I better amend my answer given that link to the wrong stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A guy named Lou Ernst on the Usenet group `alt.sys.pdp11` mentioned that he had it with sources [back in 2011](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/alt.sys.pdp11/WAZa8hJOwk0/LFPMwSLyiQEJ):

> Last night we finally got CAPS-11 running on our 11/04 with TA11/ TU60. Jack R. was given a set of original DEC CAPS-11 cassettes during
> one of his recent expeditions. These included bootable cassettes,
> object files, and all the sources. He mailed them to me, and I was
> able to recover the contents of these original 37 year old tapes on my
> TU60.

A person going by the name of "paramucho" comments that

> I didn't know it was missing! I've had this V3.0 magtape distribution
> sitting a directory for a while now:
>
> http://pdp-11.org.ru/files/rsx-11/ias30sys.zip
>
> Described below as a TU10 distribution:
>
> http://mailman.trailing-edge.com/pipermail/simh/2006-December/003803.html
>
> I tried to install on a simulated RL02 it tonight under SIMH. It boots
> up nicely and asks all the right questions, but after doing the badblk
> check all I get are disk errors and then tape errors (I can't get E11
> to run on 64-bit Windows and my emulator doesn't do tapes).




<strike>The zip file linked contains a TU tape image. I poked around in it and there's plenty of readable ASCII but I couldn't identify whether or not it contains what you want. You'll probably have to mount it in an emulator or find tools for listing/extracting the files.</strike>

Update: It turned out that the guy in that thread who thought he had the same files had something else after all, so his links were of no use.

If not then some of the names and email addresses in that thread should lead you to somebody who can get you a copy.

Spoiler: OP did receive a copy from Lou!

Comment: Hm. For me it contains `IAS30SYS.TAP`, but it doesn't seem to be a SimH tape, at least. As for IAS, it looks like another [operating system](https://www.john-a-harper.com/ias.html) with at least some similarities to RSX. So I am not sure if the link is about CAPS-11. But nice find.

Comment: Oh. I didn't see the file extension since Windows hides them by default but it shows a Spectrum emulator icon and I know that both TU58 and Spectrums use image file formats with the [DSK extension](https://www.ak6dn.com/PDP-11/TU58/) since I've been working on a DSK tool that can distinguish them all. I did not realize that both TU58 and Spectrum also both use a file format with a TAP extension. TAP sure makes more sense than DSK for a tape image format though (-:

Comment: Lou says in another post that he's given it to the appropriate place for archiving, but not who that is. I suppose the PDP-11 people in the group would all know. Also of note, it comes up a couple of times in that thread that nobody could find the manual and that's the one piece that today is easy to find on the internet.

Comment: Anything called IAS30SYS.TAP is surely an IAS 3.0  system tape.  IAS is (loosely speaking) RSX-11D with timesharing support and the then-new Digital Command Language (DCL) as the primary UI, rather than MCR.   It's a "large PDP-11" OS, at the opposite end of the spectrum from CAPS-11.

Comment: [An IAS overview](http://www.john-a-harper.com/ias.html) from one of its implementers.

Comment: I contacted ernst and he supplied the full source code!! Is there a place for retro OS sources, I could load it there

Comment: It would be nice to get it on bitsavers.org.